# Segmenting a color wheel

Tags: python

I'm a fan of elegant ways to condense code. I find this ugly. Been staring at it for a while, can't think of a way to write this with less verbosity (ok, short of shorter var names but that's not what I mean). What do you guys think?

```
if angle < 60:
    red = 1
    green = angle / 60
    blue = 0
elif angle < 120:
    red = 1 - (angle - 60) / 60
    green = 1
    blue = 0
elif angle < 180:
    red = 0
    green = 1
    blue = (angle - 120) / 60
elif angle < 240:
    red = 0
    green = 1 - (angle - 180) / 60
    blue = 1
elif angle < 300:
    red = (angle - 240) / 60
    green = 0
    blue = 1
else:
    red = 1
    green = 0
    blue = 1 - (angle - 300) / 60
```

Replying to a request for context:

```
# a color wheel is drawn using aggdraw like so (the list of 360 colors I've obviously omitted but is contained in 'colors', as are several self-evident vars

for i in range(360):
            brush = aggdraw.Brush(colors[i])
            center = surface_width // 2
            inner_radius = radius - 2
            surface.polygon((center, center,
                           int(round(inner_radius + math.sin((rotation - .25) * PI / 180) * inner_radius)),
                           int(round(inner_radius + math.cos((rotation - .25) * PI / 180) * inner_radius)),
                           int(round(inner_radius + math.sin((rotation + 1.25) * PI / 180) * inner_radius)),
                           int(round(inner_radius + math.cos((rotation + 1.25) * PI / 180) * inner_radius))),
                          brush)
            rotation += 1
            if rotation > 360:
                rotation -= 360
```

Comment: The mathematical operations `sin` and `cos` come to mind. Could you explain what this code does and why it does it? Can you show some image that shows the different colors depending on the angle?

Comment: This is for determining where, on a rotated color wheel, someone had clicked given the color in question. I didn't write the code which generates the color wheel,  but it's longish and generally takes a list of pre-determined colors and then blends between them (I work in cognitive psych and we use this as a diagnostic in case it wounds like a bizarre demand of a color wheel).

Comment: (But for your reference, I've now included the code that generates the color wheel from which we want to infer angle given color; I'm a UX guy, haha, that this is probably condensable with trig occurred to me but is beyond me; mostly I was wondering if there is some nifty pythonic way of expressing this more cleanly)

Comment: @SimonForsberg This code seems to handle decoding a HUE angle to RGB components from an edge of a HSV color wheel — see the image in the answer to this question : http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/226940/what-is-pink-and-what-is-magenta

Comment: This is not code you authored?

Answer (score 3):

Not a proper methodology nor a code-review but I'll try to explain what I've done.

First, I've put your code in a function returning the `(red, green, blue)` tuple.

Then, I wrote a tiny bit of code to find the different values taken by the different colors :

```
prev_t = None
for i in range(362):  # Going a bit further than 360 just out of curiosity
    red, green, blue = foo(i)
    t = blue  # Change this if you care about a different color
    if t != prev_t:
        print(i, t)
    prev_t = t
```

For the blue color, I got :

```
(0, 0)
(180, 1)
(360, 0)
```

which led me to think that the blue value was 1 for values bigger than 180 (because the comments talked about wheels, it made sense to apply a modulo 360).

I got a bit lucky because I started with the blue color which was the easiest. Now, the blue value can be computed with :

```
angle_blue = angle % 360
blue = angle_blue >= 180
```

Then, I applied a pretty similar trick to other colors by changing the line `t = blue` and I realized that they could be computer with a similar logic but with an additional shifting.

Now, the code can be written :

```
def foo2(angle):
    angle_blue = angle % 360
    blue = angle_blue >= 180

    angle_green = (angle - 60) % 360
    green = angle_green < 180

    angle_red = (angle - 120) % 360
    red = angle_red >= 180

    return red, green, blue
```

(This code could be written in a more concise way but this version corresponds to the fact that I've progressed by handling one color at a time).

This seems to be working for all tested values as per the assert added to the loop I originally wrote :

```
for i in range(362):  # Going a bit further than 360 just out of curiosity
    red, green, blue = foo(i)
    red2, green2, blue2 = foo2(i)
    assert red == red2
    assert green == green2
    assert blue == blue2
```

Answer (score 1):

- when you have switch/case with ranges, you could try use bisect. Look `def grade` example at https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html#other-examples approach
- when you have switch/case with numbers, you could try use dictionary and get method

In both ways, your assignments

```
        red = ...
        green = ...
        blue = ...
```

should be defined as parametrized functions to call

Example:

```
    def getcolor(angle):
        thick = angle // 60 % 2 and 1 - (angle % 60) / 60 or (angle % 60) / 60
        colors = [[ 60,          1, thick, 0], # [...to_angle, red, green, blue],
                  [120,          thick, 1, 0],
                  [180,          0, 1, thick],
                  [240,          0, thick, 1],
                  [360,          thick, 0, 1],
                  [float('inf'), 1, 0, thick]]
        return colors[bisect([x[0] for x in colors], angle)][1:]
```

Comment: I like this solution; it's a touch over my head so I'm going to have to explore it a bit before up-voting or further enquiry but being pointed in this sort of direction was what I was after, thanks.